# Button widget adds new plots instead of replacing the old one

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have a function using widgets that is working just fine, but the slider is a little hard to move in small steps.

I want to add buttons to go forwards or backwards one step on click.
This is implemented in the code below. My problem is that when I call back the original function `myplot` from inside `on_button_`, it draws everything again, but I only want the updated scatter plot.

I've experimented with `plt.close('all')` and  `plt.show()` as you can see.

My problem -I think- is that I can't find the right place to put them.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual, Button, HBox, fixed

@interact 

step = 0.1
def myplot(
            x=(0.3, 3, step), 
            y=(0,8,1)):
  
        

    ###############
    def on_button_next(b):
        plt.close('all')
        myplot(x+step, y=y)

    def on_button_prev(b):
        plt.close('all')
        myplot(x-step, y=y)

    button_next = Button(description='x+')
    button_prev = Button(description='x-')
    ############################

    if x>0.3 :  
        plt.figure(figsize=(9,7))
        ax1 = plt.subplot()
        ax1.scatter(x, y, marker='*', s=300)
        ax1.set_xlim(0,2)
        ax1.set_ylim(0,8)


        ##### buttons. 
        display(HBox([button_prev, button_next]))
        button_next.on_click(on_button_next)
        button_prev.on_click(on_button_prev)
        ################

    return plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing `plt.show()` and `plt.close()` and writing instead `display(fig)` and `clear_output()`

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

step=0.1

@interact 

def myplot(
            x=(0.3, 3, step), 
            y=(0,5,1)):

        

#         ##############
    def on_button_next(b):
        clear_output()
        myplot(x+step, y=y)
    def on_button_prev(b):
        clear_output()
        myplot(x-step, y=y)

    button_next = Button(description='x+')
    button_prev = Button(description='x-')

    ##############
    if x>0.3 :  
        
        #buttons
        
        display(HBox([button_prev, button_next]))
        button_next.on_click(on_button_next)
        button_prev.on_click(on_button_prev)
        ##
        
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.scatter(x, y, marker='*', s=300)
        plt.xlim(0.3,2)
        plt.ylim(0,8)
        plt.close()
        display(fig)
```